# Could not locate method: DefaultGraphTraversal.addE() Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune, gremlinjs

For some reason I'm getting the above error when I try to use addE in my traversal.

```
const traversal = await g
    .V(id)
    .fold()
    .coalesce(__.unfold(), __.addV().property(t.id, id))
    .inE()
    .where(__.outV().hasId(bob))
    .fold()
    .coalesce(__.unfold(), __.addE().from_(__.V(bob)).to(__.V(tweetId))
    .next()
```

Any idea to what's going wrong here? That error message makes no sense to me.

This is on a Neptune server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supplying an argument to `addE()`. There is no zero-argument option to that step. You must supply an edge label as an argument either by way of `addE(String)` or `addE(Traversal)`. If you see that error in the future, it is best to check the javadoc for [GraphTraversal](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html) or [GraphTraversalSource](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversalSource.html) when you see that.